# Open small activity on top of interact-able activity

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, modal-dialog

I want to open activity TopActivity on top of activity BottomActivity, while TopActivity is much smaller than BottomActivity.
So user can interact with both TopActivity and BottomActivity at the same time.

Like in modal dialog, BottomActivity should remain visible.

**But unlike modal dialog, BottomActivity should remain enabled and interact-able**.

***Please note that TopActivity is inherited from a 3rd party Activity, so it must be activity and not fragment, view, etc.***

How can I accomplish that?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

This is not how Android works. You are only able to display one activity at a time on an android screen. The 3rd party library has to have fragment implementations.

Comment: Not precise. I know at least two methods to DISPLAY more than one activity at a time - smaller dialog activity and an activity with transparent background. But I want to interact with activities, not just  display them.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to accomplish something like this using a RelativeView as the bottom view and adding another view in the code to act as the top view, but its not going to be pretty.

Comment: Well, as I've indicated in the question: it must be activity and not fragment, view, etc.